# Filtering documents (.docx) and web pages (html/aspx) files in Fast Search for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

We are setting up FAST Search for SharePoint environment and to provide certain back-end Audit we developed and application which returns the metadata of all the fields to know what is in and what is not.

The user can select the Metadata properties (Managed Properties like DateCreated, Author, Title etc) from the list and enter a keyword. This will result a tabular data which contains the details of selected Metadata columns.

Now the problem comes when the user just wants to filter the results to certain file type. For example: If the user wants to see Metadata for just documents(.docx) or sometimes for just Webpages (.html/.aspx).

Need to know if there are options with back-end to define "Search Scopes" for both these file types? or do we need to make this filter in the FQL Query ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have too much information, but there there are several options possible. The options that you mentioned are all viable options.

1. use the out of the box functionality for filtering on document type.
2. create a custom scope for your file extension. This can be done via the UI on sitecollection level.
3. create the refinement options yourself. how to do this in code: http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-refinement-query-parameter-for.html

my question to you: Is that application hosted in a SP environment (if not, option 2 is not possible, of course).

Comment: Thanks Bas. There are some things additionally wanna know.. will get back to you on this...

Comment: Ok. We figured out this. We created Scopes which crawled on specific areas of the SharePoint Site. And in the Webpart code we just added a property to  keywordQuery object, keywordQuery.HiddenConstraints = "scope:\"MyScope\"";

Answer (score 0):

1. Is very simple to show only Documents or Web-Pages is by using **isDocument** (e.g. ) managed property either in your Search Scopes or directly by modified the Search Core Results web part (on this page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134087.aspx) you can see more about, look at Basic:22(Integer) Property name.
2. One other way is to use the contentclass = STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary (see more examples here http://spreflections.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/leverage-search-crawl-rules-and-content-class-property-to-refine-sharepoint-search-result/)

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks Marius.. will try this... but I still have some questions will get back to you on this.. thanks...

Comment: Feel free to drop them on this forum precisely and for sure we shall answer as quickest as possible!